# How to merge columns of two files in R?

Tags: r, merge, names

I have two files A and B:

First file A has columns whose names are as follows:

```
names(A) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
```

Second file B has columns whose names are as follows:

```
names(B) <- c("b","c","d","y","z","q")
```

You see some column names are same but some are not. I want to have all columns in both files.

So finally both of them should like:

```
names(A) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f",y","z","q")

names(B) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","y","z","q")
```

**with new columns in both files which were earlier not present with NA values of course.**

I am looking for some function in R which can do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `?merge`?

Comment: "merge" function merges two data frames by some column which is present in both (i may be wrong, please correct me if i am wrong). I want A file to have columns y,z,q with NA values and B file to have columns e,f with NA values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
notA <- setdiff(names(B), names(A))
notB <- setdiff(names(A), names(B))

A[notA] <- NA
B[notB] <- NA
```

If you also want to have the column names in the same order in both datasets:

```
B <- B[names(A)]
```